# Case-insensitive filename completion in `shell-command'

Tags: minibuffer, completion, case-folding

I know I can get case-insensitive filename completion in the minibuffer using [`read-file-name-completion-ignore-case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html), but this doesn't seem to apply to *all* filename completion in the minibuffer.  Specifically, it doesn't seem to apply when I'm using `shell-command`. Example:

```
$ emacs -Q
M-: (setq read-file-name-completion-ignore-case t)
M-! touch /tmp/HelloThere
C-x C-f /tmp/hello<TAB>  <-- this completes to HelloThere, as expected
M-! shell-command<RET>ls /tmp/Hello<TAB>  <-- this completes to HelloThere, as expected
C-g
M-! shell-command<RET>ls /tmp/hello<TAB>   <-- no completion
```

Is there any way to get whatever is completing `/tmp/HelloThere` while reading from the minibuffer for a `shell-command` to respect `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case`?

Answer (score -1):

Bind `tags-case-fold-search` to `t` in a function that otherwise just calls `tags-completion-at-point-function`, and put that function on `completion-at-point-functions`.

The problem you are running into is that `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` is not used, and that is because `read-file-name` is not used.

(Alternatively, you can bind `tags-case-fold-search` to non-`nil` and non-`t`, and bind `case-fold-search` to non-nil.)

Comment: So you mean like [this](https://gist.github.com/mgalgs/64b3d6282f9e14c698d7), right? Still doesn't work... :(

Comment: `completion-at-point-functions` should be a list of functions, not a single function. You can discover this using `C-h v completion-at-point-functions` or by reading the Elisp manual, node [`Completion in Buffers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Completion-in-Buffers).

Comment: Even so, `tags-completion-at-point-function` seems to rely on `etags`.  I'm not certain that `etags` is guaranteed to have all of your filename completions unless you have configured it to do so.  Is that right?

Comment: @nispio: The point is that this is the kind of completion that `TAB` provides in shell mode. Whether it does what you want in all cases is not the point. You can of course change the behavior of shell-mode completion, as you can change nearly anything in Emacs. But `tags-completion-at-point` is the completion it provides out of the box. In my own code ([**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles)), for example, I provide a [different kind of completion for shell (comint) mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Shell-Command_Enhancements).

Comment: Whoever downvoted: Care to say why? Something you didn't like?

Comment: -1, This answer is not working for the OP, and it is not working for me either.  It is either wrong, or needs more information to be helpful.

Comment: @nispio: Thx for the explanation. Sorry for your trouble. At least I explained why `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` has no effect here. And the code I suggested might at least serve as food for thought, if it does not work out of the box for you. And if you are expecting not to have  `etags` installed or not to use  `etags` then, as I say, you will need to define a different function for shell-mode completion from what vanilla Emacs uses (`tags-completion-at-point`). The code here *assumes the same thing that Emacs assumes*: that you use `etags` - nothing more than that (AFAIK).

Comment: I am not *intentionally* avoiding `etags`, I'm just not sure what I need to do to make `etags` aware of the names in my directory tree.  It would be helpful if you could add a code snippet that would work given `emacs -Q` (if that is possible).

Comment: @nispio: Someone else will need to do that. You can start with the Elisp manual, node `Tags` (and subnodes).  But you will need to also have program `etags` (or equivalent) installed. And what gets tagged depends on your source language etc. That is really outside the current question, and I have no special expertise in it.